# Sort a python list with different data types

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was asked to sort this python list and then in reverse order.

```
lst = [4,7,3,7,2,1,"Three",34,8]
```

My problem is how do you sort this if there is a string in there? My assumption is the output will look like this:

```
output[1,2,3,"Three",4,7,7,8,34]
```

Then I would use reverse() on this.

I'm not sure how to sort this or what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Why does the string go in that position?

Comment: I am not sure how to sort a list when there is a string in there. Do we just remove it or can it be sort?

Comment: @FraserGilbert: You *can* sort it—but there’s no default order for it (in Python 3), so you have to specify one.  What order so you **want** a mix of strings and numbers to go in?

Comment: if you are asked to do this sort , you should ask for clarify  , mixed data type sorting is some kind of "user defined sorting" ,  with different sorting preference ,  the string can come out in the beginning , or in the end , or in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Although I think that the question was more philosophically dealing with what the meaning of sort would be in this case, I thought I'd try it out anyway.

For this specific case you can either create a function or a dictionary to translate from words to numbers or use a library like `word2number` from `PyPi`.

For example:

```
lst = [4,7,3,7,2.6,2,-2,1,"Three",34,8, "5", "-3.5"]

def numerate(x):
    if isinstance(x,  (int, float)):
        return x
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        return trans[x.lower()]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(f"{x} is not a number")           

print(sorted(lst, key=numerate))
```

> Result: ['-3.5', -2, 1, 2, 2.6, 3, 'Three', 4, '5', 7, 7, 8, 34]

Uses a function within the sort to convert the words to numbers, although it will fail if the word is not in the `trans` dictionary. Using word2number, instead of the `trans` lookup, like (note: not tested)

```
import word2number as w2n
...
return w2n.word_to_num(x)
```

would be (a lot) more general of course.

Comment: Why `str(x).isdigit()` instead of just `isinstance(x, int)` (or `isinstance(x, (numbers.Real, decimal.Decimal))` if you need to handle arbitrary comparable numeric types)? Type converting followed by a character by character test is a weird way to go about it.

Comment: I was thinking that the list might have a string like "5", which I'd sort as the integer 5. It has the weakness that floats don't work, so a combination of `isinstance` and string to numeric conversion is probably needed to cover all possibilities.

Comment: For a string like `"5"` you'd need to return `int(x)` not just `x`.

Comment: You're right of course. Long day yesterday. I'll improve it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for any Word-Number (Three, Twenty, Seventy Nine, etc).

You would need to install [`word2number`](https://pypi.org/project/word2number/) library.

```
pip install word2number
```

## Solution

```py
import numpy as np
from word2number import w2n
def get_number(x):
    # pip install word2number
    # from word2number import w2n
    if isinstance(x,str):
        x = w2n.word_to_num(x)
    return x

lst = [4,7,3,7,2,1,"Three",34,8]  
data_nums = [lst[y] for y in np.array([get_number(x) for x in lst]).argsort()]
```

#### Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 'Three', 4, 7, 7, 8, 34]
```

### Another Possibility

What if you want to express the previously sorted values (in `data_nums`) in terms of their word-equivalent representation?

You may need to install [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/0.5.2/) library: `pip install num2words`.

```py
import num2words as n2w
def get_word(n, titlecase = True):
    # pip install num2words
    # import num2words as n2w
    if not isinstance(n,str):
        w = n2w.num2words(n)        
    else:
        w = n
    if titlecase and isinstance(w,str):
        w = w.title()
    return w

data_words = [get_word(x) for x in data_nums]
data_words
```

Output:

```
['One',
 'Two',
 'Three',
 'Three',
 'Four',
 'Seven',
 'Seven',
 'Eight',
 'Thirty-Four']
```

Comment: `for y in list(someiterable)` is an anti-pattern; if it's convertable to `list` (e.g. the result from `argsort`), it's already an iterator, and you can just iterate it directly and avoid the unnecessary temporary `list`, e.g. in this case: `[lst[y] for y in np.array([get_number(x) for x in lst]).argsort()]`

Comment: @ShadowRanger: That’s generally quite true, but note that there are exceptions if the operation of the loop would invalidate the iterator (like storing into a dictionary over which the iteration takes place).